# Boost asio acceptor прием/отправка сообщения

Tags: boost

Взял простой `boost`овский пример эхо-сервера, который принимает сообщение и передают обратно `"Hello World"`.

На компьютерных браузерах все работает, браузеры отображают `"Hello World"`, на мобильных браузерах почему то нет, они ждут и почему то ничего не отображают.

В чем может быть причина ?

Вот мой код:

```cpp
    int main()
    {
        int port;
    port = 80;

    boost::system::error_code ec_acceptor;
    ///////////////////
    boost::asio::io_service io_services;

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor Acceptorka(io_services);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint 
    endpointo_acceptor(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port);
    tcp::acceptor the_acceptor(io_services, endpointo_acceptor);
    tcp::socket socket_acceptor(io_services);

    the_acceptor.accept(socket_acceptor);

        boost::asio::streambuf Response_read_acceptor; // объявим буффер
        boost::asio::read_until(socket_acceptor, Response_read_acceptor, "\r\n", 
    ec_acceptor); // Читаем Входяший запрос

        ///// Пришел GET запрос от браузера ....

       //// Отправляю ответ:

        string response_text_1 = "Hello World";

    boost::asio::write(socket_acceptor, boost::asio::buffer(response_text_1));
    socket_acceptor.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_send);
    socket_acceptor.close();
    }
```

На буке на хроме и интернет-експлорере все работает, сообщение приходит. На том же хроме на телефоне нет ниче, хотя сам запрос пришел, и команда `boost::asio::write` - отработана, но мобильный браузер почему-то не хочет отображать сообщение.

2) И если не сложно подскажите пожалуйста еще, как можно получить сам IP с которого пришел запрос ?
Пробовал так:

```
cout<<endpointo_acceptor.to_string()<<endl;
```

Но так не работает, выводит просто все нули.